# node.js array check fails conditional is processed even while returning false

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, node.js, null

I have a buffer in node.js and I'm checking for mime type with regex.
There is a capturing group in regex and if it is successfull it must return this capturing group at index 1 in the array returned by exec.

I'm using

```
if(mime.exec(dt)[1]){
    tip.push(mime.exec(dt)[1]);
}
```

this control and I also tried

```
if(1 in mime.exec)
```

and also

```
mime.exec.hasOwnProperty(1)
```

but anyway the condition is processed and gives traceback

```
TypeError: Cannot  read property '1' of null
```

What kind of mechanism can I use to fix this issue?

UPDATE ----

var mime=/^content-type: (.+\S)/igm;

UPDATE ----

```
var fs = require("fs"),
    mime = /^content-type: (.+\S)/igm,
    tip = [];
require("http").createServer(function(req, res) {
    var data = "";
    console.log("working...");
    console.log(req.method);
    if (req.method.toUpperCase() == "POST") {

        req.once("data", function() {
            fs.writeFileSync("dene.txt", "");
        });
        req.on("data", function(dt) {
            fs.appendFileSync("dene.txt", dt.toString("utf8"));
            if (mime.exec(dt)[1]) {
                tip.push(mime.exec(dt)[1]);
            } else {
                return false;
            }

        });

        req.on("end", function() {
            console.log(((fs.statSync("dene.txt").size) / 1024).toFixed(2), "kb");
            console.log(tip);

        });
    }
    res.writeHead(200, {
        "content-type": "text/html"
    });
    res.end(require("fs").readFileSync(require("path").resolve(__dirname, "static_files/post.html")));
}).listen(3000)
```

Comment: can you show us a more complete code example?

Comment: @lispHK01 i am adding entire code as update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this

```
if (mime.exec(dt)[1]) {
```

to this

```
if (mime.exec(dt) && mime.exec(dt)[1]) {
```

`exec` returns either null or an array -- test for null first because you can't treat null as an array.

**Edit:** as mentioned in the comments, there probably will be additional considerations to keep in mind if using a global regex.

So, for global regexes, super-safe version:

```
var rslt = mime.exec(dt)
if (rslt && rslt[1]) {
  tip.push(rslt[1]);
```

Comment: This won't work well on global regexes where each `exec()` returns a different result…

Answer (score 2):

Without more context (especially how is the value of `mime` assigned), it is difficult to say exactly what is going on, but what we can say with certainty is: `mime.exec` is `null` at the time that your code executes `mime.exec.hasOwnProperty(1)`. So fire up a debugger and watch the value of `mime` to see what's going on.

Comment: i am adding the mime variable under post @Trott

Comment: Somewhere between that assignment and where you are checking for the property, the value of `mime` is changed. It might be a case of using `=` where you mean to use `==`. It might be a scope issue. It might be something else.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your regex has the *global* flag set - compare [Why RegExp with global flag in Javascript give wrong results?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1520800/1048572). So when you call `mime.exec(dt)` the first time, it matches something and advances the `mime.lastIndex` property, but when you call `mime.exec(dt)` a second time it **doesn't find a second match** in the `dt` string.

So there are two things to do:

- Don't make it a `global` regex when you only intend to make a single match.
  Alternaticely, if you plan to reuse the object (like the multiple callback invocations in your example), make sure to either exhaust the search (typically `while (m = regex.exec(input))`) or reset `regex.lastIndex=0;` every time.
- Don't call `exec()` twice, but just store the result in a variable

Also notice that `.exec()` might not return an array at all but `null` when it doesn't match anything, so you'll anyway have to use

```
var match = mime.exec(dt);
if (match) // possibly `&& match[1]` if you need to ensure that no empty string was captured
    tip.push(match[1]);
```

Comment: but it still doesnt explain why if else statement works wrong

Comment: Which else statement do you mean, and how does it "*work wrong*"?

Comment: im checking if first index of the array whic is represented by exec defined and then making this push but anyway even if this is null the code in if block executes

Comment: Are you saying that `tip` contains unexpected values in the end? If so, please post a test case with the values of `dt` you are receiving and the expected output. Or are you refering to the `Cannot  read property '1' of null` type error? See the last paragraph of my answer.